# Как формализовать функцию проверка_прав, чтобы её можно было применить к любой другой?

Tags: python, python-3.x

В основной части программы вводится команда вида "записи(арг0) добавить(арг1) "hello world"(арг2) ". Функция проверка_прав должна определить, есть ли имя текущего пользователя в списке пользователей, имеющих право выполнять данную команду. У меня возникают трудности с формулировкой обращения к этим спискам.

```
Права = { # Тип команды : {Название команды : [Список пользователей, имеющих право]}
    "пользователи" : [
        {"добавить" : ["админ", ]},
        {"изменить" : ["админ", ]},
        {"удалить" : ["админ", ]}
        ],
    "записи" : [
        {"добавить" : ["админ", ]},
        {"изменить" : ["админ", ]},
        {"посмотреть" : ["админ", ]},
        {"удалить" : ["админ", ]}
        ],
    "права" : [
        {"добавить" : ["админ", ]},
        {"удалить" : ["админ", ]}
        ]
    }

#Функции:

def проверка_прав(арг0, арг1):
    global Права, текущий_пользователь
    #такой способ не работает. Нужно сделать так, чтобы не было необходимости 
    #указывать конкретный индекс из списка. Но как это сделать, если у списка нет имени, 
    #чтобы можно было применить метод list.index() ?
    if текущий_пользователь in Права[арг0][арг1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False


#Пример функции, с которой должна работать проверка_прав
def изменение_прав(арг0, арг1, арг2):
#Синтаксис: "Права"_Действие_"Имя пользователя"
    global Права
    if проверка_прав(арг0, арг1) == True:
        тип_команды = input("Введите тип команды")
        право = input("Введите право")
        if (тип_команды in Права) and (право in Права[тип_команды]):
            if арг1.lower() == "добавить":
                Права[тип_команды][право].append(арг2)
            elif арг1.lower() == "удалить":
                Права[тип_команды][право].remove(арг2)
            else:
                print("Неправильный ввод")
        else:
            print("Неправильно введены тип команды или право")
    else:
        print("Недостаточно прав")
```

Comment: Не сразу понял, что меня смущает в коде :) Функции и переменные на русском :D

Comment: Структура у Права странная, почему там список из словарей? Мне кажется, так правильнее было бы: `"записи": { "добавить": ["админ", ], ... }`

Comment: Точно. Чувствую себя идиотом. Два дня бился. Хотя в любом случае было бы полезно узнать, что делать в описанном мною случае.

Answer (score 0):

Взял на себя смелость сильно поменять структуру кода, т.к. считаю, что структура у `ПРАВА` неправильная, плюс:

- Для упрощения проверок структуры перенес в `проверка_прав` и добавил исключение
- Добавил явное использование аргументов в частности для текущего юзера

> Я бы добавил проверку, того, что `target_user` отсутствует в `ПРАВА[command_type][command_name].append(target_user)`, чтобы не было дубликатов, но пусть это будет заданием автору :)

```
# Тип команды : {Название команды : [Список пользователей, имеющих право]}
ПРАВА = {
    "пользователи": {
        "добавить": ["админ", ],
        "изменить": ["админ", ],
        "удалить": ["админ", ]
    },
    "записи": {
        "добавить": ["админ", ],
        "изменить": ["админ", ],
        "посмотреть": ["админ", ],
        "удалить": ["админ", ]
    },
    "права": {
        "добавить": ["админ", ],
        "удалить": ["админ", ]
    }
}


class InvalidCommandException(Exception):
    pass


def проверка_прав(user: str, command_type: str, command_name: str) -> bool:
    if command_type not in ПРАВА:
        raise InvalidCommandException(f'Неизвестный тип команды {command_type!r}!')

    if command_name not in ПРАВА[command_type]:
        raise InvalidCommandException(f'Неизвестная команда {command_name!r} для типа команды {command_type!r}!')

    return user in ПРАВА[command_type][command_name]


def изменение_прав(user: str, command_type: str, command_name: str, target_user: str):
    command_type = command_type.lower()
    command_name = command_name.lower()

    try:
        if not проверка_прав(user, command_type, command_name):
            print("Недостаточно прав!")
            return

        if command_name == "добавить":
            ПРАВА[command_type][command_name].append(target_user)
        elif command_name == "удалить":
            ПРАВА[command_type][command_name].remove(target_user)

    except InvalidCommandException as e:
        print(f"Неправильный ввод! {e}")


current_user = 'админ'
command_type = input("Введите тип команды: ")
command_name = input("Введите право: ")
target_user = input("Введите имя пользователя: ")

изменение_прав(current_user, command_type, command_name, target_user)

print('Структура прав:')
print(ПРАВА)
```

Пример работы:

1. Хороший сценарий:

   ```
   Введите тип команды: пользователи
   Введите право: добавить
   Введите имя пользователя: модераторъ
   Структура прав:
   {'пользователи': {'добавить': ['админ', 'модераторъ'], 'изменить': ['админ'], 'удалить': ['админ']}, 'записи': {'добавить': ['админ'], 'изменить': ['админ'], 'посмотреть': ['админ'], 'удалить': ['админ']}, 'права': {'добавить': ['админ'], 'удалить': ['админ']}}
   ```
2. Не поддерживаемый тип команды:

   ```
   Введите тип команды: статистика
   Введите право: посмотреть
   Введите имя пользователя: Иван
   Неправильный ввод! Неизвестный тип команды 'статистика'!
   ...
   ```
3. Неизвестное название команды:

   ```
   Введите тип команды: пользователи
   Введите право: найти по айпи
   Введите имя пользователя: МОДЕРАТОРЪ!!!
   Неправильный ввод! Неизвестная команда 'найти по айпи' для типа команды 'пользователи'!
   ...
   ```
4. Меняем текущего пользователя: `current_user = 'хакер'` и проверяем права:

   ```
   Введите тип команды: пользователи
   Введите право: добавить
   Введите имя пользователя: хакер №2
   Недостаточно прав!
   ...
   ```